# Extract audio from webm video into m4a audio files

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, webm, m4a

Can I use `ffmpeg` or another command-line tool (I recently downloaded `mkvtoolnix` for example) to directly extract audio into m4a files from webm videos?

I've previously been doing this 2-step process:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm temp.mp4
ffmpeg -i temp. mp4 -vn -c:a copy audio.m4a
```

Problems are that the first command is so slow, seemingly needlessly slow as the second command completes consistently in less than a second. Also, it's a pain to have to alternate between the two different commands.

Is there a single command I can use to put the audio of a webm video in a .m4a audio file?

I am also looking for a solution for `.mkv` files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FFmpeg only writes AAC / ALAC / AC3 codec audio to M4A, normally not featured in WebM containers, so you will have to use

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vn audio.m4a
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't even try this. Why does `mp4` require the `-c:a copy`?

Comment: It doesn't. If the output format supports the input's audio codec, then `-c:a copy` is preferable since it skips recompressing the data. But you can always transcode.